# JSON.parse(hr.response) error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to retrieve data from JSON. I have written this code. It alerts "1" but doesn't alert "2".

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax_get() {
        var results = document.getElementByI("results");
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        hr.open("GET", "mylist.json", true);
        hr.responseType = "JSON";
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json",true);
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                alert('1');
                var data = JSON.parse(hr.response);
                alert('2');
                alert(data);
                results.innerHTML = data.name;
            }
        }
        hr.send(null);
        results.innerHTML = "request ...";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">ajax_get();</script>
</body>
```

Comment: looks at the debug console -- do you see any errors there?

Comment: Why are you sending a `Content-type` header with a `GET` request? It has no content.

Comment: @Soren there is at least error or typo with `document.getElementByI` instead of `document.getElementById`

Comment: without Content-type  how to write get can please explain clearly

Comment: @Regent -- the point is that the JSON.parse is not needed as the request is already for a JSON type, and the browser debug output would clearly say that

Comment: @PenumatsaPradeepVarma the `Content-Type` header is used to specify to the server what content you are sending it. You are not sending any content, so just remove that line - it's unnecessary

Comment: it was just printing request..... thats it than i kept alert('1') and 2 but its just print alert 1

Comment: @Soren and my point is that `document.getElementByI` will produce error just in the first line before problem with `JSON.parse` comes. Even though since `alert('1');` works, it makes sence that it is typo in code here, in SO.

Comment: @Regent agree it is probably a typo -- i'm sure that both errors would show up in the debug console -- .... if just people would read the error messages instead of asking questions....

Comment: @Soren  document.getElementByI  its a typo error

Answer (score 3):

You have already set the response type as json on this line.

```
hr.responseType= "JSON";
```

So you need not parse the response again. it will be by default json.
Make sure your response is in json format and change your code like this.

```
 var data  = hr.response;
```

Comment: its moving to next line but its getting error at results.innerHTML = data.name;

Comment: {"name":"pradeep"}  in mylist.json